# Creating a word list

Tags: passwords, privacy

Is there anything out there that can create a word list with the following parameters?

- Password contains [string_1] = aaaaaaaaaaaaa
- Password also contains [string_2] = bbbbbbbb
- [string_1] comes before [string_2], i.e [string_1][string_2]
- There is an unknown string between them and an unknown string at the end. ie. 
  [string_1][unk_1][string_2][unk_2]
- [unk_1] and [unk_2] have: min length = 1 , max length = 3 , only contain             characters [123!]

Altogether there isn't a massive amount of combinations compared to how long the password is. Is there anything I could use as my coding ability is slightly lacking.

Examples of password:

- aaaaaaaaaaaaa12!bbbbbbbb13!
- aaaaaaaaaaaaa12!bbbbbbbb1!
- aaaaaaaaaaaaa12!bbbbbbbb2!
- aaaaaaaaaaaaa!23bbbbbbbb12!
- aaaaaaaaaaaaa!bbbbbbbb12
- etc.

If anyone really wants to know why I need this... A very old .rar file of mine has a password in this format. Painful stuff guessing all this time.

Comment: `crunch` or a simple shell script could do all that. Please search here for "word list" or "password dictionary".

Comment: Unfortunately, this is basically a scripting question, and might be a better fit on StackOverflow.

Comment: It's almost codegolf-worthy **zsh, 89 characters:** `x='1,2,3,!';y="{{$x},{$x}{$x},{$x}{$x}{$x}}";eval print -l aaaaaaaaaaaaa${y}bbbbbbbb${y}`

Comment: I don't think this question would do well on either [SO] or [SoftwareRecs.SE]. For Stack Overflow, it should at least show the code that the OP had already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a little script that (hopefully) is what you need. I am not sure this was the right place for you to ask this, but here you go, anyway (This is a python 3 script):

```
string1 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
string2 = "bbbbbbbb"
out = open("someFile.txt",'w+')
unkPos = ["1","2","3","!",""]
unkAllOptions = []
for x in unkPos:
    for y in unkPos:
        for z in unkPos:
            unkAllOptions.append(x+y+z)
unkAllOptions = [val for val in unkAllOptions if val != ""]
for unk1 in unkAllOptions:
    for unk2 in unkAllOptions:
        out.write(string1+unk1+string2+unk2+"\n")
out.close()
```

There are, of course, much better ways of doing this, that don't create duplicates and so on. But since the resulting word list is pretty small, I allow myself doing this the quick and dirty way.

Comment: Thanks man! I'll try this out straight away. Trying to crack my own password has made me want to get in to coding even more!

Comment: @T.BJ Happy to help! If this ends up solving your problem, please consider marking my answer as a solution ;) Good luck.